# How do I take physical backup of PostgreSQL data directory, which is encrypted using encfs

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to take physical/filesystem backup of PostgreSQL data directory.The challenge is, data directory is encrypted and is not visible.I tried tar,rsync but they are not working, as data directory is invisible.

Please guide me a way to take physical backup of encrypted postgreSQL data directory

- Postgres version: 9.6.8
- OS:CentOS 6.6
- Environment: test

encfs command used:

```
encfs -o nonempty /pgsql/postgredb/data_enc/ /pgsql/postgredb/data
```

Below is the data directory

[image: the data directory]

Comment: How can you even run Postgres if the data directory is not visible? But if Postgres works, you should be able to take a backup using [`pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html)

Comment: Postgres will run.Just the contents of data directory is invisible.I can see the contents if I decrypt it.